# Is there Peace based Martial Arts style dance council and teamwork readily working?

Tags: exercise

Are there Dance communities intent mostly on fitness within the martial arts spectrum that might be there to join and socialize within peaceful means instead of defense tactics?Are there links to persons that I could Martial Arts Dance with?

I'm 39 years old and have specialized in Martial Arts since the age of 7.  I trained and worked with some pretty big names in Martial Arts through the years and grew to hate the big screen because of the social implications fame has in 'entertainment' based Martial Arts.  I found a lot of peace in dance when I got upset about those Guardianship issues I get to deal with when someone famous is in on Martial Arts Security.

As things go I ran into a captivity situation about two and a half years ago where self defense tactic was a little useless because of the weopons used to threaten in the issue.  After then I have gotten into staying as calm and peaceful as I can and realize I like the fast pace of Martial Arts I just care to avoid absolutely the full sum of hand to hand defense tactic as a means to keep my mind set on peace.  When I thought on this I thought back to when I used to dance because of the fame issues, and later in life I used to Dance a lot with security teams and in one on one team based OVE joinings.  Since then the work is so much more built up on tactic, and there was a Dance movement of one kind I saw in the work processes of security I got going on still I don't have those communications now.  I'm looking to find OVE ones in Martial Arts style Dance because I need the heightened rate of intensity and bond of OVE of that kind of joining, in some way you could say as council after what I went through in the captivity issue.  Are there links to those that might could help me find a Martial Arts Dance community in my Home Area?...  ;I'm looking as in a Creator to establish full OVE based peace with no more involvement in situations that might include defense at all.  I've danced martial arts style dancing before still I have no one to dance with, and need to get in shape.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "OVE"?

Comment: As a prophetic truth insight, Ove is the old linguistic use of the word most people now a days attribute to have a "L" inclusive spelling, the added "L" at the front of the word comes from the French term of "Le" denoting a thing; still OVE as Creator and Maker does not personally care to be made out to be a thing... I don't mean to just jump into usage of the old or traditional usage of the word without this being made clear logically

Comment: As a side note, that's not where "love" comes from, at least in English. That sounds like a confusion with why we use "love" in tennis scoring, which *is* a corruption of ""l'œuf", or "the egg", representative of the zero.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... some schools of Capoeira would fit the bill for you. Most of them still do the martial aspect, or at least teach you how to perform the movements martially, but the emphasis is not on striking the other person, or even on defeating them, but rather crafting a narrative with them, suiting your movements to there, trying to intermesh and create something greater than the sum of the parts.

Note, of course, that not all Capoeira schools practice non-competitive non-striking playing in the *roda*. Some of them practice a very martial variant of it, and many have a very strong focus on showing off and gaining a high degree of athleticism. If you have a choice of schools, I would recommend focusing on *Angola* or *Benguela* version *Regional* or *Contemporanea* which tend to be faster and more martial.